# Python, Django: how to get checked table rows into lists?

Tags: python, html, django, html-table, submit

Good evening,

I'm hoping someone knows an answer to my problem of getting all checked rows inside a table into a multidimensional list (after submit)?

I know I can do something like this to get - for example - all the checked ids into a list:

**template:**

```
<form action="" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}

    <div class="table-wrapper">
        <table class="table table-hover">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th scope="col"></th>
                    <th scope="col">id</th>
                    <th scope="col">country</th>
                    <th scope="col">continent</th>
                    <th scope="col">...</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                {% for item in data %}
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <input type="checkbox" name="list_gap" value="{{ item.id }}">
                        </td>
                        <td>{{ item.id}}</td>
                        <td>{{ item.country }}</td>
                        <td>{{ item.continent}}</td>
                        <td>...</td>
```

**views.py**

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    checked_data = request.POST.getlist('list_gap')
```

But as mentioned, this will only get me a list of the checked ids! Is there a way to get **all** the data of the row into a multidimensional list, for example like..?

```
list_checked = [
    [1, 'country', 'continent', '...'],
    [2, 'country', 'continent', '...'],
    [3, 'country', 'continent', '...'],
    ...
]
```

Thanks for all your help and a good night!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd recommend creating a queryset to pull the instances from the DB.

```
checked_data = request.POST.getlist('list_gap')
checked_instances = Model.objects.filter(id__in=checked_data)
```